# Opening a .msg file in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-9.10

Someone sent me a .msg file on Skype, and somehow I just can't open this in Ubuntu.

Is there any app in which I could open the .msg file?

Comment: This could be many things...what type is this file? There are several different programs using the msg extension.

Answer (score 125):

This is an MS-Outlook format. There is a command line tool called MSGConvert (see [www.matijs.net/software/msgconv](http://www.matijs.net/software/msgconv/)) which converts .msg files into .eml. You can open those with Thunderbird or Evolution. On Ubuntu you should be able to install the tool using

```
sudo apt-get install libemail-outlook-message-perl libemail-sender-perl
```

from a command line. Use

```
msgconvert *.msg
```

to convert every file in a directory at once. MSGConvert will produce copies of your .msg-files with the suffix .msg.eml. Regardless, your friend should learn how to send content properly.

Comment: Somehow msgconvert didn't appear in the path, but the following worked: `perl -we 'use Email::Outlook::Message; print Email::Outlook::Message->new(shift)->to_email_mime->as_string' foo.msg >bar.eml`

Comment: Just to note, on debian based systems the msgconvert script isn't in the package.

You can get it from the repo however here: https://github.com/mvz/email-outlook-message-perl

Comment: Using the msgconvert tool from https://github.com/mvz/email-outlook-message-perl, the command line `./msgconvert file.msg` produces nothing. You have to use `./msgconvert --outfile file.eml file.msg`.

Comment: If you already did `apt-get install libemail-outlook-message-perl`, you don't need to do anything more. That package already contains `/usr/bin/msgconvert`, at least on Debian 8 Jessie.

Comment: +1 for rational note at the end

Comment: Best feasible solution, the rest is crap.

Comment: I just get a base64 string that still needs decoding.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian  mixed in with the base 64 stuff should be a clear area where the message is decoded in plain  text.   You might need to scroll up to see it.  Or pipe the output into 'more' *(or less)* so that you can paginate your way down to where the email text is revealed.

Comment: Worked perfectly on Ubuntu 22.04. I wonder what is in `.msg` files. My `.msg` file is 150 KB, whereas the converted `.eml` file is only 34 KB. Furthermore, the smaller `.eml` file is plain text with an embedded ASCII HEX binary, whereas the `.msg` file is pure binary. Usually, binary files are *more* efficient than ASCII text files, not less.

Comment: Worked great. The eml file could be viewed and I could display the source as text as I needed.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with slightly broken files.

Answer (score 53):

Use Microsoft one drive to open .msg files online via browser:

Sign in to your Microsoft onedrive account and upload the .msg file. After upload, you can click on it to view the file contents.

The advantage over other answers is you won't be sharing your file with third party file converters.

Note: This method is Non-OS specific and can be applied in any OS.

Comment: I wish I could edit the message also.

Comment: @Jaakko .msg files are email conversation thread. I coundn't find any sense of editing it. I think you can copy text content for forwarding mail purposes

Comment: despite that fact this is not a _solution_ for the problem, in some particular cases your suggestion works very good!

Comment: @radistao thanks for the compliment. I say you don't have to convert the file to open .msg you just need to use Microsoft tools. for ubuntu, it's only in web and an electron version i.e nothing but the web. 

& yeah it definietly solves the problem of viewing .msg and therefore it can be treated as solution :P

Comment: After opening a .msg file on the OneDrive (using current Google Chrome) I can read the message body but I don't see a way to open attachments contained in the message and listed on the Attachments line.

Comment: Does it contain any attachments? are you able to view attachments in outlook on windows?

Comment: The disadvantage of this method is that you will be sharing the email with Microsoft.

Comment: LOL @neuhaus Microsoft owns outlook. They already have your entire outlook inbox, not just that email with you are trying to read by drive upload.

Comment: @AkhilSurapuram no they do not have your email if you use Outlook on your own Exchange server.

Answer (score 17):

It's not perfect but you can import `.msg` file with [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) *(it works with on 52.1.1 on my Linux Mint)*. **I had some encoding error but you can globally read the content.**

In Thunderbird you click on *File* > *Open* > *Saved message* and select your `.msg` file.

Comment: For my case, with this method, the file is totally unreadable.

Comment: This kind of works. I can see a plain text message at the top with a lot of issues under it but I think it has got the text content of the email right.

Comment: There is no encoding error it simply than the encoding of the Outlook file (*.msg) is ANSI. I have the following in my .bash_profile :

    function msgread() {
        msgconvert --outfile - "$1" | iconv -f ms-ansi -t utf-8  | less
    }

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Most likely cause: Windows uses UTF16, while Linux uses UTF8.

Comment: Worked great for a couple of old Outlook messages I had failed to convert over. The messages were text only. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Another free and cross-platform tool for extracting the contents of an Outlook msg file from the command line is [msg-extractor](https://github.com/TeamMsgExtractor/msg-extractor).

```
pip install extract-msg
extract_msg file.msg
```

Please note that while package name uses hyphen, command name uses underscore.

https://pypi.org/project/extract-msg/

Comment: This works but doesn't preserve the mail headers.

Comment: Worked for me when I needed to extract an attachment out of a .msg file. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

Try this link:  https://www.coolutils.com/online/Mail-Converter/

I came to this post searching for an answer, found the above link which did the job for me. Hence wanted to share here.

If you are concerned about privacy, you can buy their desktop version and convert it.

Comment: @VirtualDXS - Life is harsh, isn't it ? :)

Comment: I also downvote this "solution", because it violates privacy. .msg files sometimes contain mail threads, which must be kept confidential.

Comment: I don't get where the tool violates privacy. It's just a wrong statement. It's the same saying Winrar violates privacy because sometimes .rar files contain files which may be confidential. Or an SQLite client violates privacy because you can read Skype conversations from .db file.

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo: It’s the difference between an online tool and a local program.  When you process data with WinRAR or any other program on your computer, the data stay on your computer (unless it’s infected with spyware). But with this “coolutils” solution, you upload your file to their website and then download the result.  Do they immediately delete your data off their servers?  Are their personnel allowed to look at your data?  Do they sell your data to other people? Once you give it to them, it’s out of your control.

Comment: People should convert .msg files to smth like pdf before sending to not get poeple such problems opening. Most computers can open pdf without installing anything additionaly or sending to webservice like this.

Answer (score 7):

I ran across such a file as well (provided to me by a colleague who saved an email message in Microsoft Outlook). `file(1)` identifies the .msg file like so:

```
foo.msg: Composite Document File V2 Document
```

Georg Jung's answer regarding Matijs van Zuijlen's perl-based `msgconvert(1)` utility steered me in the right direction.  Although my system does not at the time of this writing have the msgconvert utility packaged, the install instructions on Matijs' web page indicate using `cpan` as one way to install it:

```
cpan -i Email::Outlook::Message
```

The cpan URL is http://search.cpan.org/dist/Email-Outlook-Message/

Answer (score 4):

You can also proceed like this:

```
strings foo.msg |html2text
```

Comment: this is bad, because you do not get the pictures

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Windows, Mac, or another Linux than Ubuntu, or you don't want to install random packages on your system, I'd recommend building on [Georg Jung's answer](https://superuser.com/a/979603/118213) by using [this docker container](https://github.com/tulequ/docker-msgconvert):

```bsh
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/mails --user $UID: lequoctuan/msgconvert my-file.msg

# takes a minute ...

cat my-file.eml
```

Comment: Isn't a docker container from someone just the same as a random package?

Comment: kind of, but you gain at least some form of isolation through docker and most importantly don’t clutter your system with a bunch of perl packages.

Answer (score 4):

I've had luck with the [MsgViewer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msgviewer/) application in Ubuntu, but it requires Java to work. The other option is to use an online viewer/converter, such as [MsgEml.com](https://msgeml.com).